# Software to find the most occurring unique words in a file

Tags: language-agnostic

I remember once visiting a website that would present a **book/novel summary** in the most interesting way. It would show a **list of words that were repeated most often in that book and which were unique/uncommon.** In other words, it would show the maximum frequency words but not common words like the, I, you etc. Then it needs to have things like showing a phrase if that is repeated often. For example, Treasure Island would probably have words like - pirates, storm, fought, treasure, pieces of eight, island, Long John Silver, Jim, omen etc.

This was the most interesting way to quickly get a good feel of whether I would like reading that book or not. I cannot find that website anymore. So I thought of looking for a software that would do the job. I have a couple of books in pdf and doc format which I would like to have analyzed. Does anyone know of a good tool/software out there that can do this?

Of course I could probably code this myself but it sure would be nice to not reinvent the wheel. So my question is, **"**do you know of any such software?**"**

Thanks,
Mugen
(bookworm)

Comment: well, if you can copy the entire text of the book, maybe http://www.wordle.net/ will work for you.  It creates tag clouds and renders them in different ways, which are pretty cool.

Comment: Amazon has a version of this called [Statistically Improbable Phrases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistically_Improbable_Phrases).

Comment: Simple enough problem to make an interesting diversion: [Code golf: Word frequency chart ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169051/)

Comment: Thanks to all for your responses. 

@Dave: wordle.net works perfectly. I can copy paste my books into it and get a good idea. Thanks a load. Too bad I don't have the option to mark a comment as the answer to the qs. Could you post your comment as an answer so I would be able to mark this qs answered?

@Matthew: I checked Amazon but it seems they don't have it for all books. Only selected ones. Besides I also found another website called shelfari.com which also seems to have a similar feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Wordle.net](http://www.wordle.net/). It creates tag clouds and renders them in different ways.

Answer attribution: [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214071/dave)