# Awk script to select files and print file sizes

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, awk

I'm working on a home work assignment. The question is:

> Write an `awk` script to select all regular files (not directories or
>   links) in `/etc` ending with `.conf`, sort the result by size from
>   smallest to largest, count the number of files, and print out the
>   number of files followed by the filenames and sizes in two columns.
>   Include a header row for the filenames and sizes. Paste both your
>   script and its output in the answer area.

I'm really struggling trying to get this to work through using awk. Here's what I came up with.

```
 ls -lrS /etc/*.conf |wc –l
```

will return the number `33` which is the number of files `.conf` files in the directory.

```
 ls -lrS /etc/*.conf |awk '{print "File_Size"": " $5 "   ""File_Name and Size"": " $9}'
```

this will make 2 columns with the name and size of the `.conf` file in the directory.

It works, but I don't think it is what he's looking for. I'm having an AWKful time.

Comment: I find it pretty awd that your instrawcter is teaching you awk at this late era in Unix history. There are a lot of better ways to write readable scripts, and if your instrawcter insists awn teaching you unreadable styles, then at least you could lawrn perl.

Comment: Standing awvation on that comment!! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see here...

> select all regular files (not directories or links)

So far you haven't addressed this, but if you are piping in the output of `ls -l...`, this is easy, select on

```
/^-/
```

because directories start with `d`, symbolic links with `l` and so on. Only plain old files start with `-`. Now

> print out the number of files followed

Well, counting matches is easy enough...

```
BEGIN{count=0}  # This is not *necessary*, but I tend to put it in for clarity
/^-/ {count++;}
```

To get the filename and size, look at the output of `ls -l` and count up columns

```
BEGIN{count=0}
/^-/ {
  count++;
  SIZE=$5;
  FNAME=$9;
}
```

The big difficulty here is that `awk` doesn't provide much by way of sorting primitives, so that's the hard part. That *can* be beaten if you want to be clever but it is not particularly efficient (see the awful thing I did in [a [code-golf] solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3169562/2509)). The *easy* (and unixy) thing to do would be to pipe part of the output to `sort`, so...we collect a line for each file into a big string

```
BEGIN{count=0}
/^-/ {
  count++
  SIZE=$5;
  FNAME=$9;
  OUTPUT=sprintf("%10d\t%s\n%s",SIZE,FNAME,OUTPUT);
}
END{
   printf("%d files\n",count);
   printf("  SIZE    \tFILENAME"); # No newline here because OUTPUT has it
   print OUTPUT|"sort -n --key=1";
}
```

Gives output like

```
11 files
  SIZE          FILENAME
       673      makefile
      2192      houghdata.cc
      2749      houghdata.hh
      6236      testhough.cc
      8751      fasthough.hh
     11886      fasthough.cc
     19270      HoughData.png
     60036      houghdata.o
    104680      testhough
    150292      testhough.o
    168588      fasthough.o
```

(BTW--There is a `test` subdirectory here, and you'll note that it does not appear in the output.)

Comment: Very thorough, thank you! The step by step explanation is a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this should get you on your way -

```
ls -lrS /etc/*.conf |  
awk '
BEGIN{print "Size:\tFilename:"} # Prints Headers
/^-/{print $5"\t"$9} # Prints two desired columns, /^-/ captures only files
END{print "Total Files = "(NR-1)}' # Uses in-built variable to print count
```

**Test:** Text after # are comments for your reference.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] ls -lrS /etc/*.conf |  
awk '
BEGIN{print "Size:\tFilename:"}
/^-/{print $5"\t"$9}
END{print "Total Files = "(NR-1)}'
Size:   Filename:
0       /etc/kern_loader.conf
22      /etc/ntp.conf
54      /etc/ftpd.conf
105     /etc/launchd.conf
168     /etc/memberd.conf
242     /etc/notify.conf
366     /etc/ntp-restrict.conf
526     /etc/gdb.conf
723     /etc/pf.conf
753     /etc/6to4.conf
772     /etc/syslog.conf
983     /etc/rtadvd.conf
1185    /etc/asl.conf
1238    /etc/named.conf
1590    /etc/newsyslog.conf
1759    /etc/autofs.conf
2378    /etc/dnsextd.conf
4589    /etc/man.conf
Total Files = 18
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first find the files with something like `find /etc -type f -name '*.conf'` ; so you get the right list of files. Then you do `ls -l` on them (perhaps using `xargs`). And then using `awk` should be simple.

But I don't think that if I did more your homework that would help you. You need to think by yourself and find out.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not a shell expert.

Thought I'd give this a go, been beaten on speed of reply though :-) :

```
clear

FILE_COUNT=`find /etc/ -name '*.conf' -type f -maxdepth 1 | wc -l`

echo "Number of files:  $FILE_COUNT"

ls -lrS /etc/[^-]*.conf | awk '

BEGIN {print "NAME     |     SIZE"}\

{print $9,"     |    ",$5}\

END {print "- DONE -"}\

'
```

My output is ugly :-( :

```
Number of files:        21
NAME     |     SIZE
/etc/kern_loader.conf      |     0
/etc/resolv.conf      |     20
/etc/AFP.conf      |     24
/etc/ntp.conf      |     42
/etc/ftpd.conf      |     54
/etc/notify.conf      |     132
/etc/memberd.conf      |     168
/etc/Symantec.conf      |     246
/etc/ntp-restrict.conf      |     366
/etc/gdb.conf      |     526
/etc/6to4.conf      |     753
/etc/syslog.conf      |     772
/etc/asl.conf      |     860
/etc/liveupdate.conf      |     861
/etc/rtadvd.conf      |     983
/etc/named.conf      |     1238
/etc/newsyslog.conf      |     1590
/etc/autofs.conf      |     1759
/etc/dnsextd.conf      |     2378
/etc/smb.conf      |     2975
/etc/man.conf      |     4589
/etc/amavisd.conf      |     31925
- DONE -
```

Comment: Pipe through `column -t` to fix the alignment :]